# checkbox reappering even if unticked on refreshing

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

I have a bunch of text box on which I have chosen to show and hide on change event using toggle with Jquery.

```
$(".category_check").change(function(){

//alert("abhiram")
// alert()
//alert($(this).data('category'))
$("#" + $(this).data('category')).toggle();
});
```

Now when I refresh with the box still checked. The tick still remains in the check box and the text box supposed to be toggled is not visible. When i uncheck the box it appears again. The opposite logic that is show when unchecked and hide when checked is happening for that checkbox alone. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code in the view of the rails app with which the script is associated with

```
 <label>Categories</label>
      <% ClipCategory.all.each do |category| %>
          <%= form_tag "update_amount", :remote => :true do %>
          <div class="span12">
            <div class="category_check pull-left" data-category="category_text_<%= category.id %>">
              <%= check_box_tag "category", 1, ( @performer.clip_category_ids.include?(category.id) ? "checked" : false ), :class => "pull-left" %>  
              <%= label_tag "category", category.name, :class => "pull-left category_label" %> 
            </div>
            <div id="category_text_<%= category.id%>" class="category_text">
              <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium" %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag "category_id", category.id %>
              <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
             </div>
          </div>
            <br />
          <% end %>
```

Comment: show your HTML as well

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: @harshini http://jsfiddle.net/B4XbE/1/

Comment: The fiddle does seem to work fine but When I refresh in the local system the tick won't go but the text box does. When I untick the checkbox the textbox appears and tick the checkbox the textbox disappears

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger the chane event

```
$(".category_check").change(function(){

//alert("abhiram")
// alert()
//alert($(this).data('category'))
$("#" + $(this).data('category')).toggle();
}).filter(':checked').change();
```